# Realtime Webcam video stitching with EmguCV

Tags: c#, webcam, emgucv, image-stitching

i am trying to do a webcam stitch in real time with EMGUCV. Something similar to 
[this setup on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GH1p1HtNegY&feature=related).
The problem is I am not getting a stitched video only images.

This is my code
`

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        capture1 = new Emgu.CV.Capture(0);
        this.capture1.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920.0f);
        this.capture1.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080.0f);
        capture2 = new Emgu.CV.Capture(1);
        this.capture2.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920.0f);
        this.capture2.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080.0f);

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region if capture is not created, create it now
        if (capture1 == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture1 = new Emgu.CV.Capture(0);
                capture2 = new Emgu.CV.Capture(1);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        if (capture1 != null)
        {
            if (captureInProgress)
            {  //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text
                // "Start" for resuming capture
                button1.Text = "Start!"; //
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;



            }
            else
            {
                //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button
                // Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
                button1.Text = "Stop";
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }

            captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
        }
    }
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture1.QueryFrame();
        camimageBox.Image = ImageFrame; //line 2
        Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame2 = capture2.QueryFrame();
        imageBox1.Image = ImageFrame2;
    }

    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (capture1 != null)
            capture1.Dispose();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Image<Bgr, byte>[] frames2 = new Image<Bgr, byte>[2];
        //List<Image<Bgr, Byte>> frames2 = new List<Image<Bgr, byte>>();
        frames2[0] = capture1.QueryFrame();
        frames2[1] = capture2.QueryFrame();

        camimageBox.Image = frames2[0];
        imageBox1.Image = frames2[1];

        try
        {
            using (Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(true))
            //using (Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(true))
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> result = stitcher.Stitch(frames2);
                imageBox2.Image = result;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (Image<Bgr, Byte> img in frames2)
            {
                img.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am using Nvidia NVS 450 GPU. I am able to read the individual cameras as seperate streams. I was wondering if I could combine the streams together using EMGUCV to produce one stream (more like 2 webcams in a virtual webcam).

I am will be grateful for any help giving. PLS  mind my English!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to find corresponding points on 2 image frames (SURF type of algorithms if cameras positions are separately controlled or you can use chessboard pattern and find corresponding corners if cameras have fixed relative position and angle), then use coordinates of those points to calculate homography matrix. When you have a matrix you use it as parameter for "WarpPerspective" function. It will warp your image so that it can be put over the frame from second camera.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hello OscylO thanks. Sorry for the late reply. I have very busy with other stuff. I will check what you have written and give you a feedback as soon as it is ok